# Calling onStart or other Android lifecycle methods yourself

Tags: android

Is it bad practice to call the Android activity lifecycle methods yourself? I have a list view that sets itself up with data from a SQLite database every time the onStart method is called, and when I delete one of the rows in the list view I call onStart to setup the list view again with fresh data from the database. Is this bad practice?

Comment: better create an AsyncTask that handles the data retrieval from database

Comment: "Is this bad practice?" -- in a word, yes.

Comment: You should not be doing this at all.  You should be using an adapter and notifyDatasetChanged.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html

Answer (score 2):

Why not do something like this:

```
public void onStart() {
    setUpDatabase();
}

private void setUpDatabase() {
    // do your thing
}


    // elsewhere...
    setUpDatabase();
```

That way you avoid the bad practice of calling callback functions out of their normal code paths.

Answer (score 1):

The better practice here is too create a new method called `refreshData()` for example and call that method in the `onStart()` and whenever else you may need too instead of calling `onStart()` again.